# How to set Path to ChromeDriver for Cucumber running on Jenkins server in Ruby?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Cucumber with Capybara to run automation test in Jenkins server. Everything works fine with Firefox. However, I got problem with setup Google Chrome and ChromeDriver. I have installed Google Chrome and ChromeDriver (moved chromedriver to usr/bin/chromedriver) but when the test runs, it notifies an error:

```
"Unable to find the chromedriver executable. Please download the server from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver."
```

Below is my setup in env.rb for Chrome driver:

```
  Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, :switches =>
      %w[--ignore-certificate-errors --disable-popup-blocking])
  end
```

How can I set path to ChromeDriver when register_driver? Have anyone experienced this issue before?
Many thanks.

Comment: you need to put chrome driver in the `PATH` variable on the machine where you are running the tests... can you execute `echo $PATH` command and check whether chromedriver path is there or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You either need to put the driver in the PATH or you should be able to call

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = <path to chromedriver>
```

before initializing the driver

Answer (score 11):

For selenium 3.x this `Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = <path to chromedriver>` **is deprecated**. Now you have to put chrome_driver path in declaration of driver:

`Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, :driver_path => <path to chromedriver>)`

Comment: As 2019 is also deprecated. :driver_path is deprecated. Use :service with an instance of Selenium::WebDriver::Service instead.

Comment: ```Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, {browser: :chrome, :driver_path => %x( which chromedriver).split("\n")[0]})```

Answer (score -2):

You have to download [ChromeDriver](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html). Unzip the file and put it in any folder that is in your PATH. In short, move the file to Ruby folder, probably C:\Ruby22-x64\bin

Answer (score -2):

Please place the chromedriver.exe in the same folder/location as the ruby.exe. That worked for me